# Swift BLE Device - write value

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have 0x010303757372707764 to write to a ble device. I know to use writeValue method

```
peripheral.writeValue(data, for: characteristics[i], type: .withResponse)
```

But I want to write 0x010303757372707764 as data. How do I do that?

Let me know if you need more information! Thank you!

Comment: Is that a 72-bit integer or a string, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UInt8` Sequence initializer for Data:

```
init<S>(_ elements: S) where S : Sequence, Self.Element == S.Element
```

For your example, this would be:

```
let data = Data([0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x75, 0x73, 0x72, 0x70, 0x77, 0x64])
```

Answer (score 0):

**For this you have to use UInt8 Array value like this "Array"**

When you write data in Peripheral.writeValue at time you have to pass that UInt8 value as Data() function.

**Let me share one example like this**

let CmdRequestTempLogSize = "#requestTempLogSize$"

let writeData = Data(CmdRequestTempLogSize.bytes)
//* CmdRequestTempLogSize.bytes put your UInt8 value*

**For bytes you can use string extension (Right now I am using String value to convert into Byte(UInt8)**

```
public var bytes: Array<UInt8> {
    return data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)?.bytes ?? Array(utf8)
}
```

Hope this example you can understand how to convert data into Byte Array

Comment: The value this question is asking about is not a UTF8 string, so this answer doesn't apply. And converting a String to Data to `[UInt8]` and then back to Data is over-complicated. Even if you wanted to convert a String to UTF8 Data, the code would be `Data(string.utf8)`. There's no need for optionals.

Comment: In your example the 0x01, 0x03, 0x03 etc is notting but UInt8 value so in my example I just explain that same logic with UInt8 Array.

Comment: Yes, but most `[UInt8]` are not valid UTF-8 sequences, so the string you're describing can't exist. This particular string of bytes turns out to be because all the values are smaller than 0x80, but that's a coincidence. I agree that a `[UInt8]` is a good tool for building a Data. A String is a bad tool (if it doesn't represent text).